# Reduce ggplot display time for large plots/maps in RShiny

Tags: r, performance, ggplot2, shiny, r-leaflet

I have 51 * 10 maps organized as a list of st objects.
My aim is to plot my 51 maps along the 10 timestep (ech) in a ShinyApp. The timesteps can be selected by the user in the ui part.

The problem is that it takes too much time : 7 to 8 seconds for one plot. Consequences : the selection in the ui part is quicker (with the animation) than the load of the plot. With plots taking 7 seconds, the users will never use the app...

I am searching for solutions to reduce this time.
The plot object is created once, the part taking time is the display of the plots with ggplot (and renderPlot). First, I tried to plot with leaflet : plot the polygons, and just updating the value associated to the polygon when the user changes the input. I could do it with one map, but impossible to plot the 51 maps in the same plot with leaflet (I tried with sync and latticeView but it didn't take less time and it was tricky to adjust the position of the maps).

Reproducible example :

```
require(leaflet)
require(leafsync)
require(shiny)
require(shinyWidgets)
require(sf)
require(ggplot2)

### Create data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

All <- list()
for(ech in 1:10) {
  All_m <- data.frame()
  for(n in 1:51) {
    All_m <- rbind(All_m,
                   data.frame(nc, number=n))  
  }
  
  All[[ech]] <- All_m
}

####ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderTextInput("ech", "Select ech", choices = as.character(c(1:10)), animate = TRUE)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("map")
    )
  )
)

#### Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    
    ##In my real code, this should be done inside the server function as I cannot load my data before running the app
    if(!exists("p_all")) {
      p_all <- list()
      for (ech in 1:10) {
        p_all[[ech]] <- (ggplot(st_as_sf(All[[ech]])) 
                         + theme_bw()
                         + geom_sf(aes(fill=PERIMETER)) 
                         + facet_wrap(~ number, nrow=5)
                         + theme(axis.title=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text = element_blank()))
      }
      
      p_all <<- p_all
    }
    
    print(input$ech)

    ###Object created once, display according to "ech"
    output$map <- renderPlot({
      p_all[[as.numeric(input$ech)]]
    })
    
    print("Im done")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Do you have any tips or advices to help me reduce this display time ?

Comment: Are displayed data static ? If so precompute plots, store them as separate images and display them using for example imageUI/renderImage

Comment: It is static data, which is computed/loaded once the user click on one specific button in the ShinyApp. If I store them with png(), should I write them somewhere?

Comment: Yes. eg in a sub folder of your application. Using renderImage you need to provide the relative path to the png file (see documentation). Better name your png according to the selected parameters in order to compute the filename from them

Comment: I'll try tomorrow if I can't find anything else. I will have to remove them once the app is closed as I cannot store the plots every days without flushing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but here is a couple of remarks:

- include a spinner which shows itself when Shiny is calculating, e.g. with **shinycssloaders**, **shinybusy**, or **waiter**; then waiting for a plot is less boring
- don't nest an `output` slot inside an observer, this is bad; you can use a reactive conductor as I do below
- use `bindCache` in order that a plot that already has been displayed will be immediately displayed if the user requests it again

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinycssloaders)

### Create data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

All <- list()
for(ech in 1:10) {
  All_m <- data.frame()
  for(n in 1:51) {
    All_m <- rbind(All_m,
                   data.frame(nc, number=n))  
  }
  
  All[[ech]] <- All_m
}

####ui
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderTextInput(
        "ech", "Select ech", choices = as.character(c(1:10)), animate = TRUE
      )
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      withSpinner(plotOutput("map", height = "600px"))
    )
  )
)

#### Server
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  GGplots <- reactive({
    p_all <- list()
    for(ech in 1:10) {
      p_all[[ech]] <- ggplot(st_as_sf(All[[ech]])) 
                       + theme_bw()
                       + geom_sf(aes(fill=PERIMETER)) 
                       + facet_wrap(~ number, nrow=5)
                       + theme(axis.title=element_blank(), 
                               axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
                               axis.text = element_blank())
    }
    p_all
  })
  
  output$map <- renderPlot({
    GGplots()[[as.numeric(input$ech)]]
  }, height = 600) %>% 
    bindCache(input$ech)
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I don't know why `height` has no effect, looks like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions ! I have a loading bar, I just didn't put it in the example. I'll try to separate observes and the outputs, quite tricky with the code, but I'll check. The user will certainly plot the figures only once. So bindcache is not very useful. But I can have a loading time before changing the cursor. Is there a way to "load" the 10 plots, and then to have no loading time when the user move the cursor, even for the first time ?